# In visual studio code, how do you jump to the actual code in a typescript type definitions index.d.ts?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

For example I command click on the `express()` function to jump to it's definition:

`const app = express();`

vscode then jumps to this line inside an index.d.ts file:

`declare function e(): core.Express;`

Doing a `Jump to Definition` / command-click on the `e()` function just puts me back in the same file.  But I would like to see the actual javascript code that underlies the types wrapper without having to search for it somewhere in node_modules.

How do you do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to the TypeScript source file instead of the type definition file in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711065/go-to-the-typescript-source-file-instead-of-the-type-definition-file-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

As of VS Code 1.24, his is not possible in general for third party node modules. VS Code uses those `*.d.ts` file to provide good intellisense without having to process the original implementation files. You can find more information about this [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition)

Using typings files is more reliable and performant, but it also means that we cannot jump back to the original JS implementation.