# vscode - replace typescript definitions with node_modules definitions

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am a big fan of vscode. Here's my question, let's say I have a code like this.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
```

when I `CMD+Click` on `express`(inside `require`) or on `get` function, it's taking me to it's typescript definition which is cached in home folder. When I clear the cache, then it's taking me to definitions inside `node_modules` and the cache is getting build again. Whereas in `webstorm`, there are no `typescript` caching, it takes me into `node_modules` definition. Is it possible to disable typescript definitions and use `node_modules` definitions ??

[image: as shown in the picture, when I click on <code>express</code> it takes me to tyepscript definition, not the <code>node_modules</code> one.]

as shown in the picture, when I click on `express` it takes me to tyepscript definition, not the `node_modules` one.

There is a built-in extension called `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features (vscode.typescript-language-features)`. Disabling that will work ?? I don't know but I am afraid that I lose `javascript` intellisense.

Anyone know ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view original javscript library source code in VS Code and not the typescript version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464407/how-can-i-view-original-javscript-library-source-code-in-vs-code-and-not-the-typ)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to the TypeScript source file instead of the type definition file in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711065/go-to-the-typescript-source-file-instead-of-the-type-definition-file-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 5):

The "cache" is built by a feature called [Automatic Type Acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition).  You can disable it by setting VS Code's `typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition` setting to true or creating a `jsconfig.json` file containing `{"typeAcquisition": {"enable": false}}`.  You'll still have to manually remove previously downloaded type declarations in order for links to take you to the implementation JavaScript files.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470832) for some additional related information.

Comment: Hey @Matt thanks for the answer... this answers my question.

Comment: One question though, will it disable intellisense and autocompletion ??

Comment: Completion will be enabled, but it won't be as accurate for JavaScript libraries that have DefinitelyTyped declarations as it would be if you enabled Automatic Type Acquisition.

Comment: Okay, but in webstorm it was so accurate... I wondered how they are doing it??

Comment: How to "manually remove previously downloaded type declarations"?

Answer (score 1):

The cache is most probably generated by the mentioned extension. You should not use it to get Typescript Typings, because Typescript's intellisense works out of the box very well.

Do not forget to install typings for each JS package.

```
npm install @types/express -D
```

Also in Typescript you should use import, instead of require:

```
import * as express from 'express'
```

Comment: hey, actually you didn't get my question, I am not coding in typescript, I am using javascript, but when you cmd+click on external libraries, vscode will take you to it's typescript definitions.

Comment: refer to the image

Comment: Sorry, unlike you, i code in typescript :) so I lack bare JS experience. But I suggest you to try TS! Much less problems!