# "Go to Implementation" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, resources, implementation

Version 1.52.1
I have `require ('stream');` in my code. I highlight *stream* and open the context menu. I select "Go to Definition" and the "stream.d.ts" file opens. It's good. Then I select "Go to Implementation" in the same way and ... "stream.d.ts" opens again. Is it possible and how to implement that the "Go to Implementation" the **implementation** is opened?

Comment: I found the answer: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6209#issuecomment-756197509

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to the TypeScript source file instead of the type definition file in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711065/go-to-the-typescript-source-file-instead-of-the-type-definition-file-in-vs-code)